# Swift 4 Json Encoding and Decoding

Tags: arrays, json, swift4, jsonparser

Here is my code to get complete Json;

```
var str = "Hello"
var dictionary = ["key1":"val1", "key2":"val2", "key3":"val3"]

var products = [Product]()

struct Product: Codable {
    var title: String
    var reference: String
}

func createProducts(title: String, refer: String) {
    products.append(Product(title: title, reference: refer))
}

for element in dictionary {
    createProducts(title: element.key, refer: element.value)
}

var general = [str: products]

let encodedData = try? JSONEncoder().encode(general)
let json = String(data: encodedData!, encoding: .utf8)!
print(json)
```

My Json dict is as follows;

```
{"Hello":[{"title":"key2","reference":"val2"},{"title":"key3","reference":"val3"},{"title":"key1","reference":"val1"}]}
```

and after decoding of Json, i only need to get this part;

```
[{"title":"key2","reference":"val2"},{"title":"key3","reference":"val3"},{"title":"key1","reference":"val1"}]
```

i have issue with decoder below, to get value of "Hello";

```
if let decodedData = try! JSONDecoder().decode(general.self, from: json.data(using: .utf8)!) {
    print(decodedData)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual type of the encoded JSON is `[String:[Product]]` so decode that and get the value for `Hello`

```
do {
    let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode([String:[Product]].self, from: Data(json.utf8))
    print(decodedData["Hello"]!)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Alternatively create an umbrella `Root` struct

```
struct Root : Decodable {
    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey { case hello = "Hello" }
    let hello : [Product]
}
```

and decode that

```
do {
   let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: Data(json.utf8))
   print(decodedData.hello)
```